# What Can I Do If Music Playback Pauses upon Song Switchover on the Status Bar

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, quickapps-cms

In my Huawei quick app, during music playback, when a user switches to another page in the app, and switches to playing another song using a status bar, the music playback pauses. How does it occurs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Listen to `audio` events on the app home page, not only on the playback page. In this way, when the user leaves the playback page, each `audio` event can still be listened to, so as to control the playback logic.

Note: Huawei Quick App Engine does not support calling of the `audio` API in `app.ux`. Therefore, when a user exits the app, the quick app cannot receive the `audio` event callback even though the music is still playing in the background.

The following demo has two pages: `Main` (home page) and `Audio`. To avoid repeated code and ensure maintainability, separate the code for the `Audio` page as a common JavaScript for each page to call.

1. public `utils.js`:

```
import audio from '@system.audio';
export default{
     listenAudio() {
         var that=this;
        console.info("util.js listenAudio ");
        audio.onplay = function () {
            console.log('audio onplay')
          }
        audio.onpause = function () {
            console.log('audio onpause')
          }
    
          audio.onended = function () {
            console.log('audio onended')
          }
 
          audio.ondurationchange = function () {
            console.log('util.js ondurationchange')
            var total = audio.duration
            console.log('util.js ondurationchange total=' + total)
          }
    
          audio.ontimeupdate = function () {
            var time = audio.currentTime
          //  console.log('util.js ontimeupdate time=' + time)
          }
    
        audio.onprevious = function () {
            audio.cover = 'https://xx.jpg'
            audio.title = "Piano music"
            audio.artist = "Mozart"
            // Replace with the music resource link.
            audio.src = 'https://xx.mp3'
            console.log(' util.js on previout event from notification ')
        }
    
        audio.onnext = function () {
            audio.cover = 'xx.jpg'
            audio.title = 'Pop';
            audio.artist = 'Michael Jackson'
            // Replace with the music resource link.
            audio.src = 'https://xx.mp3'
            console.log(' util.js on next event from notification ')
        }
    },
    
     getAudioPlayState() {
        audio.getPlayState({
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(`getAudioPlayState success: state: ${data.state},src:${data.src},
                      currentTime:${data.currentTime},autoplay:${data.autoplay},loop:${data.loop},
                      volume: ${data.volume},muted:${data.muted},notificationVisible:${data.notificationVisible}`);
                                 },
            fail: function (data, code) {
                console.log('getAudioPlayState fail, code=' + code);
                            }
        });
    },
    
     startPlay() {
        audio.play();
    },
    
     pausePlay() {
        audio.pause();
    },
    
     stopPlay() {
        audio.stop();
    },
    
     seekProress(len) {
        audio.currentTime = len;
    },
    
     setVolume(value) {
        audio.volume = value;
    },
    
     setMute(isMuted) {
        audio.muted = isMuted
    },
    
     setLoop(isloop) {
        audio.loop = isloop
    },
    
     setStreamType() {
        if (audio.streamType === 'music') {
            audio.streamType = 'voicecall'
        } else {
            audio.streamType = 'music'
        }
        console.error('audio.streamType =' + audio.streamType);
    },
    
     setTitle(title) {
        console.info('setTitle=' + title);
        audio.title = title;
    },
    
     setArtist(artist) {
        console.info('setArtist artist=' + artist) ;
        audio.artist = artist;
    },
    
     setCover(src) {
        console.info('setCover src=' + src);  
        audio.cover = src;
    }
}
```

2. Add an `audio` event listener to the lifecycle method `onShow` of the `Main` page and call `listenAudio` in `utils.js`. Sample code:

```
<script>
  import utils from '../Util/utils.js';
  module.exports = {
    onShow(options) {
       utils.listenAudio();
    },
  }
</script>
```

3. Add an `audio` event listener to the lifecycle method `onShow` of the `Audio` page, and call `listenAudio` in `utils.js`. The progress callback event is listened separately because the playback progress needs to be displayed on the playback page. Sample code:

```
  onShow(options) {
      var that = this;
      utils.listenAudio();
      audio.ondurationchange = function () {
        console.log('audio ondurationchange')
        that.total = audio.duration
        console.log('audio ondurationchange total=' + that.total)
      }
 
      audio.ontimeupdate = function () {
        that.time = audio.currentTime
        console.log('ontimeupdate time=' + that.time)
      }
    },
```

For more details, please check the following guide:

[Quick App Audio Development Guide](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/quickApp-References/quickapp-api-audio?ha_source=hms1)